# C#, how to set method from one class to check values between said class and another class and display end result?

Tags: c#

I have a question ...have been messing around with it but can't really get my logic into the code so the compiler would get me. So long story short what the code must do is: 
Sean (my class is a bit picky towards his partners)
Girlfriend is a separate class and the age of the girls should be randomly generated in the program each time a girl is instantiated.
In the main method of the program instantiate 3 girls using a suitable constructor.
Instantiate an object representing Sean with only name, age and girlfriend. Use again suitable constructor for easy instantiation. During the instantiation set one of the girls.
Call the Seans method “CheckMatch()”. Swap the girl and call again the method. Do this for all 3 girls.
There should be an internal mechanism for generating random numbers for the age of the girls.

What I have done so far is:

```
namespace Gfs
{
class Girlfriend
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public  int age { get; set; }
    public string hairColor { get; set; }
    public string eyeColor { get; set; }
    public static int counter { get; set; }
    public static Random rnd = new Random();

    public Girlfriend(string name, string hairColor, string eyeColor)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.hairColor = hairColor;
        this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
        this.age = rnd.Next(20, 30);
        counter++;
    }

}
}




namespace Gfs
{
class Sean

{
    private string name = "Sean";
    private int age = 24;

    public void sean(int age, string name)
    {
        name = this.name;
        age = this.age;

    }


    Girlfriend gf1 = new Girlfriend("Vicky", "Blonde", "Blue");
    Girlfriend gf2 = new Girlfriend("Liz", "Blonde", "Blue");
    Girlfriend gf3 = new Girlfriend("Sharon", "Blonde", "Blue");
    public void CheckMatch()  

    {         
        if (age <= (gf1.age+5) && age >= (gf1.age-1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("She is a match");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("She is not a match ");
        }
    }


}

}
```

I am currently calling the girls in the Class Sean because I don't get how to create the method "CheckMatch()" in Sean then assign the values for the check itself when I call the method in the Main() (currently interested in the age check itself I could possibly fix it myself for eye color and hair color)

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Where is you Main? It seems that you are creating you have a mess on your Sean class with your gridlfriends.

Comment: Yeah.....I currently have no main except for
            Sean asd = new Sean();
            asd.CheckMatch();


which doesn't really help a lot :/

Comment: Can you formulate an actual question and put it in your title please?

Comment: Apologies, will fix it right away (however already got great answers) ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this, just basically tie things up:

```
namespace Gfs
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gfList = new List<Girlfriend>();

        gfList.Add(new Girlfriend("Vicky", "Blonde", "Blue"));
        gfList.Add(new Girlfriend("Liz", "Blonde", "Blue"));
        gfList.Add(new Girlfriend("Sharon", "Blonde", "Blue"));

        var sean = new Sean(24, "Sean");

        foreach (var gf in gfList)
        {
            if (sean.CheckMatch(gf))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("She is a match");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("She is not a match");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Girlfriend
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string hairColor { get; set; }
    public string eyeColor { get; set; }
    public static Random rnd = new Random();

    public Girlfriend(string name, string hairColor, string eyeColor)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.hairColor = hairColor;
        this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
        this.age = rnd.Next(20, 30);
    }
}

public class Sean

{
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public Sean(int age, string name)
    {
        name = this.name;
        age = this.age;
    }

    public bool CheckMatch(Girlfriend gf)

    {
        return age <= (gf.age + 5) && age >= (gf.age - 1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion. The list does make the code more compact in terms of lines (even though it is a small program). Thank you very much for the input. I am still learning the basics I suppose. :)

Answer (score 0):

First dont call the Guy class Sean. You should have a class called Guy and make an instance called Sean.

Second Guy should have a CheckMatch call that takes a Girlfriend as a paramtere adn returns a bool

```
public bool CheckMatch(Girlfriend gf)
{
   if (gf.age.....)
     return true;
   return false;
}
```

Then in your main do;

```
var sean = new Guy();
Girlfriend gf1 = new Girlfriend("Vicky", "Blonde", "Blue");
Girlfriend gf2 = new Girlfriend("Liz", "Blonde", "Blue");
Girlfriend gf3 = new Girlfriend("Sharon", "Blonde", "Blue");
if(sean.CheckMatch(gf1))
   ......
```